# Zend Framework Custom Validator on Form Elements

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am trying to set up element custom validator in a zend form this is what I have.

```
class Siteanalysis_Form_User_ChangePassword extends SA_Form_Abstract
{
  public function init()
  {

    // add path to custom validators
    $this->addElementPrefixPath(
        'Siteanalysis_Validate',
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/siteanalysis/models/validate/',
        'validate'
    );

    $this->addElement('text', 'passwdVerify', array(
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array('PasswordVerification',array('StringLength', true, array(6, 128))),
        'decorators' => array('ViewHelper','Errors',
                        array('HtmlTag', array('id' => 'passwdVerify')),
                        array('Label', array('placement'=>'prepend','class'=>'label'))),
        'required'   => true,
        'label'      => 'Confirmar contraseÃ±a nueva',
    ));

     $this->addElement('submit', 'change', array(
        'label'      => 'Cambiar',
        'required' => false,
        'ignore'   => true,
        'decorators' => array('ViewHelper')
    ));     
  }
}


 class Siteanalysis_Validate_PasswordVerification extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
 {
   const NOT_MATCH = 'notMatch';

   protected $_messageTemplates = array(
     self::NOT_MATCH => 'Verifique que las contraseÃ±s sean iguales.'
   );

   public function isValid($value, $context = null)
   {
    $value = (string) $value;
    $this->_setValue($value);

    if (is_array($context)) {
        if (isset($context['passwdNew'])
            && ($value == $context['passwdNew']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif (is_string($context) && ($value == $context)) {
        return true;
    }

    $this->_error(self::NOT_MATCH);
    return false;
  }
}
```

The problem is that its not calling the PasswordVerification custom validator, does any one see something wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume there are no PHP errors being caused by this code? What happens when you submit the form - Do the other validators work? What if you put `die('foo')` in your isValid method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Test Setup

```
    $form = new Siteanalysis_Form_User_ChangePassword();

    $value = 'Adam';
    $data = array('passwdVerify' => $value);

    $validation = $form->isValid($data);
    if ( $validation === false ) {
        $element = $form->getElement('passwdVerify');
        $errors  = $element->getErrors();
        $msg     = $element->getMessages();
    } else {
        $values = $form->getValidValues($data);
    }
```

If $value is

- empty I get $errors "isEmpty"
- 'Adam' I get $errors "noMatch" and "stringLengthTooShort"
- 'AdamSandler' I get $errors "noMatch"

Comment: now thanks to your commment to the other answer check the new update.

Comment: Yes I try that too I dont know whats going on, not even the buld in 'required'   => true parameter its working.

Comment: okay, I was finally able to set up a test env. Now, the config for elements is smarter than I expected and accepts the string as the validator. There are implementation which are not so forgiving. Surprisingly everything works fine, as much as I can tell in your code. Therefore, I wonder what you think is wrong with your implementation. I'll add my test setup up as an update shortly.

Comment: Yes thats the way I was missing the  $form->isValid($data) to check the form elements, Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your validators array should look like this:

```
'validators' => array('PasswordVerification' => array('StringLength', true, array(6, 128)))
```

not

```
'validators', array('PasswordVerification',array('StringLength', true, array(6, 128))),
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this you are saying that 'PasswordVerification' is the key of array('StringLength', true, array(6, 128)), and thats not the case these are two separate validators one is custom and the other is build in validator.